# BigTable - getting total number of rows

Tags: php, bigtable

I'm using [PHP client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-php-bigtable/tree/main/src) for working with BigTable instance. Is there a way to fetch total number of rows from the table?

So far the solution I found is to use `Filter::pass()` and manually loop through all returned results. Wondering if there is an easier way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BigTable does not maintain count of rows seprately that you can pull directly. Even the [cbt tool](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/cbt-overview) which supports count reads all the rows to get to a count. Since you are doing count you should use [Strip value filter](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/using-filters#strip-value)  `$filter = Filter::value()->strip()`. This removes all the cell values making it easy on the memory consumption.

For larger datasets where you want to avoid scan all together you could use [increment](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/samples/bigtable-writes-increment#bigtable_writes_increment-php) with your writes to maintain the count yourself.

If you are sticking with scans, for larger tables you may want to use a system like dataflow which can distribute the count process to many workers and get you the results quickly. Here is the [SourceRowCount](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-bigtable-examples/tree/main/java/dataflow-connector-examples#sourcerowcount---reading-from-cloud-bigtable) example from Dataflow.

Comment: See this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76200013/8016720) that shows how to also limit the returned columns to 1. That will minimize the about of data returned when implementing a row count. The example is in Scala but should be easy to implement in PHP.